# Hibernate gets locked on alter table command

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, playframework, hibernate-search

I have a Play Framework application, which uses Hibernate (`5.2.12.Final`) to connect to Postgresql (library version: `42.1.4`, Postgresql `9.6`). I added the following code to my application (I wanted to start using Hibernate Search, so I need session object):

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
session.flush();
```

The code hangs on the second line and application log is showing:

```
...
Hibernate: alter table creative_works_inner_tags drop constraint FK1m3t9vv4yl0o36k9nv0bjko87
Hibernate: alter table creative_works_inner_tags drop constraint FKcodcu7qrti27rqnv54bg9o0ma
Hibernate: alter table entry_headings drop constraint FK4tx66i2tsu651p4s176ea2nvk
```

So it looks like Hibernate hangs somewhere in the middle of schema update, which is triggered by session start. I also see a lock in Postresql:

```
select pid, 
       usename, 
       pg_blocking_pids(pid) as blocked_by, 
       query as blocked_query
from pg_stat_activity
where cardinality(pg_blocking_pids(pid)) > 0;

pid  | usename | blocked_by |                             blocked_query                              
-----+---------+------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------
18804| pbl     | {18499}    | alter table entry_headings drop constraint FK4tx66i2tsu651p4s176ea2nvk
```

I don't know what to do about it. It also happens with previous library versions.

**Update**

The pid that blocks the ALTER TABLE command comes from the same application:

```
 datid | datname |  pid  | usesysid | usename |    application_name    | client_addr | client_hostname | client_port |        backend_start         |          xact_start           |          query_start          |         state_change          | wait_event_type | wait_event |        state        | backend_xid | backend_xmin |                                                                                                                            query                                                                                                                            
-------+---------+-------+----------+---------+------------------------+-------------+-----------------+-------------+------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+-------------------------------+-----------------+------------+---------------------+-------------+--------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 16388 | pbl     | 18499 |    16387 | pbl     | PostgreSQL JDBC Driver | 127.0.0.1   |                 |       51192 | 2018-01-12 10:23:11.62866+01 | 2018-01-12 10:24:11.363172+01 | 2018-01-12 10:24:11.574648+01 | 2018-01-12 10:24:11.574693+01 |                 |            | idle in transaction |             |       373556 | select children0_.parent_code as parent_c3_179_0_, children0_.code as code1_179_0_, children0_.code as code1_179_1_, children0_.ord as ord2_179_1_, children0_.parent_code as parent_c3_179_1_ from record_types children0_ where children0_.parent_code=$1
```

I don't trigger this SELECT explicitly in my code. It must be another Hibernate operation which happens automatically. Also, this code fragment is not explicitly parallel.

Comment: What does session 18499 do? And yes, an `ALTER TABLE` requires an exclusive lock on the table

Comment: I'm not sure how to check it. Could you give me some hint on it? I expect it comes from the same application, since nothing else is doing anything else with the database.

Comment: `select * from pg_stat_activity where pid = 18449`

Comment: This query shows 0 rows although the lock is still there (I get the same result from the query in  my question).

Comment: Ok, I can see it now, thanks. It comes from the same application (see update).

Comment: Looks like a bug in Hibernate or your application. Transactions should *never* remain open for a long time (apart from holding locks, they will block garbage cleanup).

Comment: Is the table containing much data? Table alteration is known to be a very slow opertion when run on non-trivial schemas. Some companies can't afford them, they'll create new tables and then have migrations; takes months.

Comment: No, it only contains 53 rows (and 3 columns)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much for the comments. They helped me to solve the problem.

The problem was: I was using both `hibernate.cfg.xml` (with session obtained from `SessionFactory`) and `persistance.xml` (with another session obtained from `EntityManager`). This was a result of integrating two applications into one and I think it caused wo Hibernate sessions to be created. I integrated necessary configuration from `hibernate.cfg.xml` into `persistence.xml` (had to change format) and it helped.